# Curved sides of triangle path?

Tags: java, android, graphics, canvas, 2d

I am drawing a triangle on a Canvas, something like:

```
canvas.moveTo(0, 30);
canvas.lineTo(40, 0);
canvas.lineTo(40, 40);
canvas.lineTo(40, 40);
canvas.lineTo(0, 30);
```

And get proper triangle on my Canvas. But I need to curve the sides a little and fill that path with specific color. What is the easiest way to do this? Drawing arcs? But how to fill the object?

[image: This is what I need to get]

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT:** I noticed you were using android's canvas, not HTML Canvas, sorry. The concept is exactly the same except you'll call `quadTo()` instead of `quadraticCurveTo()`, so my example should still get you going.

Also on android you use  `canvas.drawPath(path, paint)` and pass in a paint that has its Paint.style set to FILL_AND_STROKE.

You will want to construct the path, `fill()` it, then `stroke()` it in order to get both a filled path with the stroke outline.

To get that particular shape, the easiest way is to draw two quadratic curves. A quadratic curve first needs a control point x,y then the end point x,y. The control point for both curves should be around the middle of your desired triangle. Here is an example:

```
ctx.fillStyle = "lightgray";

ctx.moveTo(0, 100);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(50, 50, 50, 0);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(50, 50, 100, 100);
ctx.lineTo(0, 100);
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();
```

[Here is that example live for you.](http://jsfiddle.net/hh3CH/11/)

Comment: Can you give us a formula for this? it will be helpful to people like me